# How To Add buttons to CKEditor's toolbar in angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor, angular7

I am using **CKEditor 5** in my **Angular 7** project.It has a default toolbar consisting of Bold, Italic, Link, Bulleted List, numbered List, Block Quote, Undo, Redo, Insert Image, and Insert Media. I want to add alignment buttons.

How to do this?

Thanks in advance.